# Search for all hotkeys starting with "g" in Vim's "quickref.txt"

Tags: regular-expression, help-system

Within the `quickref.txt` (which can be reached by typing in `:tab help quickref`) I can see plainly texts, pages after pages, that look like:

```
h       N  h            left (also: CTRL-H, <BS>, or <Left> key)
l       N  l            right (also: <Space> or <Right> key)
0          0            to first character in the line (also: <Home> key)
^          ^            to first non-blank character in the line
$       N  $            to the last character in the line (N-1 lines lower)
                           (also: <End> key)
g0         g0           to first character in screen line (differs from "0"
                           when lines wrap)
g^         g^           to first non-blank character in screen line (differs
                           from "^" when lines wrap)
g$      N  g$           to last character in screen line (differs from "$"
                           when lines wrap)
gm         gm           to middle of the screen line
gM         gM           to middle of the line
bar     N  |            to column N (default: 1)
f       N  f{char}      to the Nth occurrence of {char} to the right
F       N  F{char}      to the Nth occurrence of {char} to the left
t       N  t{char}      till before the Nth occurrence of {char} to the right
T       N  T{char}      till before the Nth occurrence of {char} to the left
;       N  ;            repeat the last "f", "F", "t", or "T" N times
,       N  ,            repeat the last "f", "F", "t", or "T" N times in
                           I want to quickly browse through all hotkeys starting with letter `g`.
```

A simple `/^g` won't return any result.

`/^\w` will return some result every paragraphs.

In the above text, in a line where string `gm` is, `/g.\{1\}\s` will NOT match the first `gm` but will match the second `gm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
/^|g
```

The `quickref.txt` file type is `help` and the underlined text (references) have a surrounding `conceal` (hidden) character (`|`) that need to be searched.

You can visualize the `conceal` character by using the command:

```
:set conceallevel=0
```

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted to know all commands starting with `g`, I would do [:h g](https://vimhelp.org/index.txt.html#g) and check this table in `index.txt` (copying here for reference).

```
2.4 Commands starting with 'g'                      *g*

tag     char          note action in Normal mode    ~
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|g_CTRL-A|  g CTRL-A       only when compiled with MEM_PROFILE
                   defined: dump a memory profile
|g_CTRL-G|  g CTRL-G       show information about current cursor
                   position
|g_CTRL-H|  g CTRL-H       start Select block mode
|g_CTRL-]|  g CTRL-]       |:tjump| to the tag under the cursor
|g#|        g#      1  like "#", but without using "\<" and "\>"
|g$|        g$      1  when 'wrap' off go to rightmost character of
                   the current line that is on the screen;
                   when 'wrap' on go to the rightmost character
                   of the current screen line
|g&|        g&      2  repeat last ":s" on all lines
|g'|        g'{mark}    1  like |'| but without changing the jumplist
|g`|        g`{mark}    1  like |`| but without changing the jumplist
|gstar|     g*      1  like "*", but without using "\<" and "\>"
|g+|        g+         go to newer text state N times
|g,|        g,      1  go to N newer position in change list
|g-|        g-         go to older text state N times
|g0|        g0      1  when 'wrap' off go to leftmost character of
                   the current line that is on the screen;
                   when 'wrap' on go to the leftmost character
                   of the current screen line
|g8|        g8         print hex value of bytes used in UTF-8
                   character under the cursor
|g;|        g;      1  go to N older position in change list
|g<|        g<         display previous command output
|g?|        g?      2  Rot13 encoding operator
|g?g?|      g??     2  Rot13 encode current line
|g?g?|      g?g?        2  Rot13 encode current line
|gD|        gD      1  go to definition of word under the cursor
                   in current file
|gE|        gE      1  go backwards to the end of the previous
                   WORD
|gH|        gH         start Select line mode
|gI|        gI      2  like "I", but always start in column 1
|gJ|        gJ      2  join lines without inserting space
|gN|        gN        1,2  find the previous match with the last used
                   search pattern and Visually select it
|gP|        ["x]gP      2  put the text [from register x] before the
                   cursor N times, leave the cursor after it
|gQ|        gQ          switch to "Ex" mode with Vim editing
|gR|        gR      2  enter Virtual Replace mode
|gT|        gT         go to the previous tab page
|gU|        gU{motion}  2  make Nmove text uppercase
|gV|        gV         don't reselect the previous Visual area
                   when executing a mapping or menu in Select
                   mode
|g]|        g]         :tselect on the tag under the cursor
|g^|        g^      1  when 'wrap' off go to leftmost non-white
                   character of the current line that is on
                   the screen; when 'wrap' on go to the
                   leftmost non-white character of the current
                   screen line
|g_|        g_      1  cursor to the last CHAR N - 1 lines lower
|ga|        ga         print ascii value of character under the
                   cursor
|gd|        gd      1  go to definition of word under the cursor
                   in current function
|ge|        ge      1  go backwards to the end of the previous
                   word
|gf|        gf         start editing the file whose name is under
                   the cursor
|gF|        gF         start editing the file whose name is under
                   the cursor and jump to the line number
                   following the filename.
|gg|        gg      1  cursor to line N, default first line
|gh|        gh         start Select mode
|gi|        gi      2  like "i", but first move to the |'^| mark
|gj|        gj      1  like "j", but when 'wrap' on go N screen
                   lines down
|gk|        gk      1  like "k", but when 'wrap' on go N screen
                   lines up
|gm|        gm      1  go to character at middle of the screenline
|gM|        gM      1  go to character at middle of the text line
|gn|        gn        1,2  find the next match with the last used
                   search pattern and Visually select it
|go|        go      1  cursor to byte N in the buffer
|gp|        ["x]gp      2  put the text [from register x] after the
                   cursor N times, leave the cursor after it
|gq|        gq{motion}  2  format Nmove text
|gr|        gr{char}    2  virtual replace N chars with {char}
|gs|        gs         go to sleep for N seconds (default 1)
|gt|        gt         go to the next tab page
|gu|        gu{motion}  2  make Nmove text lowercase
|gv|        gv         reselect the previous Visual area
|gw|        gw{motion}  2  format Nmove text and keep cursor
|netrw-gx|  gx         execute application for file name under the
                   cursor (only with |netrw| plugin)
|g@|        g@{motion}     call 'operatorfunc'
|g~|        g~{motion}  2  swap case for Nmove text
|g<Down>|   g<Down>     1  same as "gj"
|g<End>|    g<End>      1  same as "g$"
|g<Home>|   g<Home>     1  same as "g0"
|g<LeftMouse>|  g<LeftMouse>       same as <C-LeftMouse>
        g<MiddleMouse>     same as <C-MiddleMouse>
|g<RightMouse>| g<RightMouse>      same as <C-RightMouse>
|g<Tab>|    g<Tab>         go to the last accessed tab page.
|g<Up>|     g<Up>       1  same as "gk"
```